# Is there a good reference for V8 command line arguments when using node.js

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments, v8

I can't seem to find a good reference for the various command line options available with Node.js.  I'm specifically interested in those that control V8 memory usage.
e.g. --max_new_space_size, --max_old_space_size, etc.

Where can I find out what those mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you start node with the argument --v8-options, you'll get a list of all v8 related options for node.  Not sure that there is any specific DOC that outlines all these options (though would definitely be nice to have).

Comment: Thanks @AlexGad, that is helpful.  But yes a doc that provides more details would be great!

Comment: After I posted this, I thought I'd google around to see what I could find but nothing that seemed to bring it all together.  Would love to see if anyone else knows of a full doc.

Answer (score 7):

2 years and no definitive answer.  I used the v8 source as a reference:

[github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/flags/flag-definitions.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/flags/flag-definitions.h)

These should also work in chrome via `--js-flags`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a somewhat dated list of Node.js v8 flags at

https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-flags/blob/master/flags-0.11.md

This is a community driven list that provides a few details about what the option does, the unit of measure, and the default values.